# Adding a fb:like-box tag with jQuery don´t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Im trying to add a `fb:like-box` tag with some attributes to my homepage via jQuery but it results in an tag without any attributes.

Heres the code i added after loading the facebook Javascript SDK:

```
$('<fb:like-box>', {
    'href' : 'http://www.facebook.com/platform',
    'width' : '292',
    'height' : '230',
    'show_faces' : 'true',
    'stream' : 'false',
    'border_color' : '#FFF',
    'header' : 'false'
}).appendTo('#aDiv');
```

and it results in:

`<div id="aDiv"><fb:like-box></fb:like-box></div>`

It seems like jQuery dont like the facebook tags so does anybody know some workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll assume that you already have the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) initialized on your page as it is required to parse any XFBML tags.

The initial call to `FB.init()` initializes any existing XFBML tags on the page :

```
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
  status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
  cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
});
```

And for any other elements added after the initialization (as in your case), you'll need to execute the [`FB.XFBML.parse()` function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/). This will render or re-render the XFBML tags and display your like box.

As for the attributes, you have two choices

- you can just append the new like box in a single string,
- or you can use the `prop()`/`attr()` jQuery functions to set these non-standard properties.

```
var likeBox = $('<fb:like-box />');
likeBox.prop('show_faces','true');
likeBox.attr('href','http://www.facebook.com/platform');
$("#foo").append(likeBox);
```

Comment: excellant answer...solving both the tag and unrenderable error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var html = $('#aDiv').html();
$('#aDiv').html(html + '<fb:like-box href='http...' width="292" ect...>');
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right idea. But why use `html(html + ...)` when jQuery provides us with an `append()` function?

Comment: If append works in your case, you can use it. In my projectecs I almost never need to use append, because that's a rare case, it's usually a mixture of appending and prepending stuff or completely rerendering the contents of a DIV, so it's more like a habit for me to work with `html()` - works both though ;)

Answer (score 0):

why dont u just append the whole thing

```
$("#aDiv").append('< fb:like-box 
    href="http://www.facebook.com/platform"
    width="292"
    height="230"
    show_faces="true"
    stream="false"
    border_color="#FFF"
    header="false"
    />');
```